# Try/Catch Does not catch FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION in trigger

Tags: validation-rule

I have created a validation rule on Account:
[image]

Then i have written following trigger and its helper:

```
trigger updateAccount on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {

     set<String> accId = new Set<String>();
     For(Opportunity record: trigger.new){
         accId.add(record.accountid);
     }
     if(accId.size() > 0){
         updateAccountHelper.updateAccount(accId);
     }
}


public class updateAccountHelper{    
    public static void updateAccount(Set<String> accIds){
        try{
            List<Account> accList = [Select Id,name from Account where id in:accIds];
            For(Account record:accList){
                record.name = 'Updated';
            }
            update accList;
        }catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('####'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My this code does not catch `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION`. Do anybody have any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: What is your input and how you pass it?

Answer (score 4):

Add below 3 lines in your catch block. This will capture your validation rule exception in a more simpler form rather than providing a huge error line.

```
catch(exception e) 
        {
            String S1 = e.getMessage();
            S1 = S1.substringBetween('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, ' , ': [');
            Trigger.New[0].adderror(S1);
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Regards! Ruchi

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same thing. A try/catch block around an update statement was not catching an exception when a validation rule is violated, but I haven't been able to repeat the problem since first encountering it.

Using the following [Database](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) method call will capture the error in a SaveResult instance:

```
Database.SaveResult myResult = Database.update(myAccount, false);
```

This seems to work when passing "false" as the allOrNone Boolean argument, but not when passing "true".

A JSON string of the SaveResult would appear something like this when the rule is violated:

> {
>     "success" : false,
>     "errors" : [ {
>       "statusCode" : "FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION",
>       "message" : "Phone is missing",
>       "fields" : [ "Phone" ]
>     } ]
>   }

You would need to evaluate the SaveResult and apply the appropriate logic based on the "success" property. The [SaveResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm) class also provides some methods to obtain the success value, the Id of the record, and the list of Database.Error instances.

[Comparison of DML vs. Database methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "Phone" field to the query once . Might be situation that before firing the validation rule , it might be firing some other exception . Can you post the debug message in the catch block you got ?